# Subdividing square buffer in sub-units using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, grids-graticules, mmqgis

I've been trying for a while now to create a grid inside a square buffer, so that it can be divided into a pre-defined number of sub-units. Creating a grid that covers the whole area is not ideal because the grid's squares will not be properly aligned with the square buffers and I need that in order to be able to count how many grid's squares are occupied by houses inside the buffer. I have 150 buffers in a single layer, and i'd like to have the grids only inside them.

I am still quite new to GIS.

Comment: I think your question would benefit by your inclusion of a picture.

Comment: You can take the technique from this answer, just use geo-tools QGIS... https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/283360/120129

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS expressions, you can subdive any square, indifferenz of size and orientation (angle) into a freely definable number of smaller squares: 2 x 2, 3 x 3, 4 x 4 etc. Output are lines; if you want to split the initial polygon in sub-polygons, use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Split with lines` with the lines created by the expression from below.

Use the following expression with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) or [Geoemtry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see [here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) and change the value in line 4 (here: `5`): the square will be split in `n * n` little squares, based on this number (if you insert 3: 3 x 3 = 9; for 5 -> 5 x 5 = 25 etc.).

*Number set to 5: Square is split in `5*5=25` smaller squares:*
[image]

```
collect_geometries (
    with_variable(
        'no',
        5, 
        with_variable (
            'len',
            
                length (
                    make_line (
                        point_n($geometry, 1),
                        point_n($geometry, 2)
                    )
                )
            ,
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (1, @no-1),
                collect_geometries(
                    make_line (
                        line_interpolate_point( 
                            make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 1),
                                point_n($geometry, 2)
                            ),
                            @len/@no*@element
                        ),
                        line_interpolate_point( 
                            make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 4),
                                point_n($geometry, 3)
                            ),
                            @len/@no*@element
                        )
                    ),
                    make_line (
                        line_interpolate_point( 
                            make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 2),
                                point_n($geometry, 3)
                            ),
                            @len/@no*@element
                        ),
                        line_interpolate_point( 
                            make_line (
                                point_n($geometry, 1),
                                point_n($geometry, 4)
                            ),
                            @len/@no*@element
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/323190/142513) to [Drawing graticule with GDAL/OGR?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/323149/115), which basically uses the built-in `Create grid` plugin:

`Vector` -> `Research Tools` -> `Create grid`

Comment: This does only create a horizontal/vertical grid in the extent of the layer, not subdividing squares of any rotation/size